# BREW: Methods to trace BPOINT error messages

Tags: brew-framework, brewmp

Hi I'm new to BREW mobile development. And I want to know the methods on how to trace the BPOINT error messages in the simulator, like double free of memory which is the TYPE 3 of BPOINT, etc.

Thanks.
Kramkram

Answer (score 1):

use DBGPRINTF(**FILE_LINE** );
As BPOINT error messages appear in the simulator log as soon as happen it is actually very effective to put DBGPRINTF(**FILE_LINE** ) they will give you indication of if the error is before or after the statement.
put them a lot - find & fix errors then remove - it faster than you think.